# getting return value from aspx sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I've used the insert command through the code front in aspx and the output parameter is:

```
asp:Parameter Name="ReturnCustomerID" Type="String" Direction="Output"
```

and in the codebehind (C#) for `OnInserted="SqlDS_CustomerDetails_OnInserted"` i have:

```
protected void SqlDS_CustomerDetails_OnInserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    String newCustomerID;
    newCustomerID = e.Command.Parameters["@ReturnCustomerID"].Value.ToString();
}
```

But for some reason I keep getting a null for my return value... I've tried executing the stored procedure direct in SQL server and it's fine and returns a proper ID but not in the c# or ASPX.

Is there a way to directly "eval" an output param to the text of a label in the code front? i.e.

```
asp:Label ID="NewCustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ReturnCustomerID") %>'>
```

I just need whichever method to bind the ID to that label.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the "@" symbol?  `newCustomerID = e.Command.Parameters["ReturnCustomerID"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: same thing..but you would need the @ since it is an output parameter in the stored procedure

Comment: Shoot, I was hoping that ReturnValue thing was right.  Well, I'm out of ideas for the moment.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I see you have set your ReturnCustomerID parameter type to String. When returning a string from a stored procedure as a return parameter, you must set the parameter to a non-null value before the stored proc is called - even if it's an output only parameter. So you'll need to make your parameter have a direction of InputOutput:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ReturnCustomerID" Type="String" Direction="InputOutput">
```

and in the SqlDataSource.Inserting event you'll need to set a default:

```
e.Command.Parameters("@ReturnCustomerID").Value = "XXXXXXXXX"
```

See this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqlintegrationservices/thread/6c95fa58-ad54-4626-96f5-339495c1715f

and scroll down to Paul Smith's post.